# AWS Cognito failing to authenticate after adding istio sidecar to pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cognito, istio, amazon-eks

I added istio to my eks cluster. Sidecars are getting added to every pod and my Kiali dashboard is also up.

But after that I am not able to authenticate my APIs. I checked all the logs, came out to be that my pods are not able to connect to Cognito Server. I am getting following error:

`Unhandled rejection TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to`
`RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.235.142.215:443`

I went inside my pod to check if it can connect to any public DNS, I was able to ping google.com but not to aws.amazon.com

To crossverify, I removed istio from my cluster and it started working.

Got a github issue somewhat matching my issue, but that has also been closed without any solution (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10848).

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue, my istio is trying to connect to aws cognito through ssl and it doesn't have certificates. Putting certificates in istio solved this.